# lookup from multiple columns pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have 2 dataframes df1 & df2 as given below:

df1:

```
a
T11552
T11559
T11566
T11567
T11569
T11594
T11604
T11625
```

df2:

```
a   b
T11552  T11555
T11560  T11559
T11566  T11562
T11568  T11565
T11569  T11560
T11590  T11594
T11604  T11610
T11621  T11625
T11633  T11631
T11635  T11634
T13149  T13140
```

I want to have a new dataframe df3 where i want to search the value of df1 in df2. if the value is present in df2, i want to add new column in df1 returning True/False as shown below.

df3:

```
a   v
T11552  TRUE
T11559  TRUE
T11566  TRUE
T11567  FALSE
T11569  TRUE
T11594  TRUE
T11604  TRUE
T11625  TRUE
T11633  TRUE
T11634  TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for new `DataFrame` with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and converting all values to flatten array by [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html), for improve performance is possible check only [`unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) values and also check by [`in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
df3 = df1.assign(v = lambda x: x['a'].isin(np.unique(df2.values.ravel())))
#alternative solution
#df3 = df1.assign(v = lambda x: np.in1d(x['a'], np.unique(df2[['a','b']].values.ravel())))

#if need specify columns in df2 for check
df3 = df1.assign(v = lambda x: x['a'].isin(np.unique(df2[['a','b']].values.ravel())))
print (df3)
        a      v
0  T11552   True
1  T11559   True
2  T11566   True
3  T11567  False
4  T11569   True
5  T11594   True
6  T11604   True
7  T11625   True
```

Comment: @amrutha - Glad can help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df3 = df1[['a']].copy()
df3['v'] = df3['a'].isin(set(df2.values.ravel()))
```

The above code will:

1. Create a new dataframe using column 'a' from `df1`.
2. Create a Boolean column 'v' testing the existence of each value of column 'a' versus values in `df2` via `set` and [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html).

Comment: i want to search from both the columns 'a' & 'b'